# Other compile dependency by profile (maven)

Tags: maven

I'm trying to use another backend (a mock backend) depending on the profile I'm compiling with. Has anyone got a good idea on how to do that?

I could create 2 ears that use 2 different backends, but that requires a LOT of work and I don't really want that..

Comment: what is the thing that differs between these backends that you need to re-compile something? Can't you configure this in a properties file and use standard filtering? If you have different dependencies per backend then you could add those into profiles. Or extract the classes that differ into separate modules and use profiles to add one or the other dependent module. There are a lot of variations to adopt to different environments. So what does "compile other code" (below) mean?

Comment: "Or extract the classes that differ into separate modules and use profiles to add one or the other dependent module." is what I'm doing now indeed. The thing is.. I've got a module "core" where I use a persitence unit. I don't want that on a certain case. Therefor I need to "compile other code" based on the profile (poorly chosen words).

Comment: is that persistence unit in a configuration file or a java class?

Comment: Sounds wrong. Don't you use dependency injection which can be configured during runtime?

Comment: @wemu it is configured in the persistence xml.

Comment: @khmarbaise  I use dependency injection indeed, but why would I change it at runtime. I don't even want a possibility to connect to the DB. (Don't want ftp access too).

I've used the plugin javaEE pattern to solve it (Adam Bien).

Comment: if it is isolated in the persistence.xml I would say that using the standard maven filtering mechanisms should do the job. You can put the default in the pom.xml and another one in a profile. For filtering: http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-filtering/ and http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html and also http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar think for one of my project. You need to follow below steps:
1. Add  tag in pom.xml with desired profile entry.
2. Need to create run maven command with required profile
mvn -P{profile mode prod/dev} clean install

sample pom file look like

```
<profiles>

        <!-- Development profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <project.mode>dev</project.mode>
                <!-- Hibernate properties -->
                <hibernate.show_sql>false</hibernate.show_sql>
                <hibernate.format_sql>true</hibernate.format_sql>
                <hibernate.use_sql_comments>true</hibernate.use_sql_comments>
                <hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>validate</hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <!-- Production profile -->
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <project.mode>prod</project.mode>
                <!-- Hibernate properties -->
                <hibernate.show_sql>false</hibernate.show_sql>
                <hibernate.format_sql>false</hibernate.format_sql>
                <hibernate.use_sql_comments>false</hibernate.use_sql_comments>
                <hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>validate</hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>
            </properties>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
```

Comment: This is just a way to create different profiles. this doesn't let me compile other code depending on another profile (and that's just the big problem).